# Can't get the dynamic hex code attribute from a div injected into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Been struggling with this for a couple days. Currently, when a user clicks a button, the JavaScript calls the API and injects certain colors (hex codes) from the DB - 6 at a time - to change the background color of 6 divs:

```
function changeColor(id, color, name) {
    $('#colour-pallete-' + id).css('background', '#' + color);
    $('#name-colour-palette-' + id).text(name);
    $('#colour-pallete-' + id).attr('color-hex', color); //adds hex attribute
    $('#colour-pallete-' + id).attr('color-name', name); //adds name attribute
}
```

HTML:

```
<main id="pallet-container" role="main" class="row inner main-body h- 
 100">
  <?php for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++) { ?>
    <div id="colour-pallete-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="main-colour- 
       palette" >
      <div class="colour-details-container py-4">
        <div class="colour-details">
          <button class="btn btn-success palette-btn add- 
             to-cart-btn" type="button"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus fa- 
             fw"></i></button>
          <button id="fav-colour-pallete-<?php echo $i; ?>" 
            class="fav-colour-pallete b  tn btn-secondary palette-btn" 
            type="button">
              <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
          </button>
            <p id="name-colour-palette-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="name- 
           colour-palette text-lg text-bold">Conton Candy <?php echo 
            $i; ?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end colour palette -->
            <?php } ?>
    </main>
```

So that works fine. But now I'm trying to take the hex code of a particular div - click of a button on that div - and inject it here:

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 favorites">
      <p class="h6 favorites-title mb-0 mt-2">Favorites:</p>
        <ul class="list-inline favorites-list mb-0">
          <div id="fav-colour-select-">
            <li class="list-inline-item fav-color" id="reds"></li>
          </div>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

With the following code:

```
 function e (id, color) {
     $('#fav-colour-pallete-' + id).click(function getFav() { //Button
        $('#fav-colour-select' + id).attr('color-hex');
      });
 };
```

Not even getting an error message in the console. I can get the console to show the hex-code of the onclick by adding the above code to the changePallete function, but then when the user clicks to change the 6 colours it multiplies that hex by however many times the user has clicked. And I still can't add it as an attribute.

Comment: Can you apply some snippet for that?

Comment: Yes sure, how do i do that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ - choose jquery as your js library then just make it running so we can get how it works and then save and share link here

Comment: @JohnEhrmantraut which parts do i need to add - there is an api and db too?

Comment: The site is live would a link be easier?

Comment: Please add a html JavaScript/JQuery example. Also: What are you trying to achieve with the function e? Do you want to get or do you want to set the value of the 'color-hex' attribute?

Comment: @enxaneta I want to take the color-hex attr of colour-palette-(1-6) and inject that into the fav-colour-selector - to change it's background. Can i share the link to the live site? Im not sure how to use js fiddle

Comment: This gets the value of an attribute: `.attr( attributeName )` This set the value of an attribute:` .attr( attributeName, value )`. You don't have a value so you get.

Comment: @Gerard its in the HTML on line 10

Comment: Yes sure it's trypaint.co.za @JohnEhrmantraut

Comment: `$('#colour-pallete-2').attr('color-hex')` it's working for me. I can get value of that, didn't you missed `-` in `$('#fav-colour-select' + id).attr('color-hex');` here? @LexRidley

Comment: Yeah that does work - the problem is only if it's in the changeColor () function. And then it does that weird thing where it multiplies the hex by the number of clicks/keydowns - eg  if a user has clicked twice (6) 65GHF (console.log) - not sure if this is a problem? And then I still cant take that hex and inject it @JohnEhrmantraut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get it working! The color-hex attribute was changing but not the background. Then I remembered the hex has to convert to RGB and change the background attribute:

```
$('#fav-colour-pallete-' + id).click(function getFav() { 
   var favColor = $('#colour-pallete-' + id).attr('color-hex');
   $('.fav-color').attr('color-hex', favColor)
   $('.fav-color').css('background', '#' + favColor);
});
```

Thanks so much to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data-colorhex` attribute instead of `color-hex`

You can access `data-colorhex` attribute with:

`$('.something').data('colorhex')` or `$('.something').attr('data-colorhex')`

This is a right way of setting additional attributes.

If you want to set it just simply do that:

`$('.something').data('colorhex', 'newValue')` or `$('.something').attr('data-colorhex', 'newValue')`

Comment: Giving this a try now. What does the 'data-' do?

Comment: data- is a attribute that can hold kind of HTML variables. So data-text='whatever' can be accessible from JS with $(element).data('text'). Can you provide me with URL to your website so I can have a look?